# Fail compilation if imports from Package B exist in a class in Package A

Tags: java, spring, gradle, onion-architecture

I am working on a Spring Boot project and am following the Onion Architecture, where each component is a different package. My build tool is gradle.

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/understanding-onion-architecture/

Example: I have packages named controller, infrastructure, application, domain and core as per Onion Architecture.

My question is: I want to disallow imports from "infrastructure" package in "domain" package and fail the build automatically. Is there a way to achieve this either in Java or Gradle?

Comment: I think it might fit better as a unit test which would check for improper imports, which you can run separate from the build. They wouldn't necessarily be _incorrect_ (per being "buildable" java code), but they're not something you would consider correct per design. These can also do some direct parsing of the source files to check that the package and imports don't "mismatch" in an inappropriate way.

Comment: We use ArchUnit (https://www.archunit.org/) for this purpose. It can not only check improper imports but also other constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at ArchUnit https://www.archunit.org/ it allows you to implement this kind of constraint in a unit test form, You can then hook that into your build/CI to block changes breaking your rules.